# Force re-run of failed Gitlab test or disable test caching

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using Gitlab and using with the following test description:

```
   ldap:
   stage: test
   script:
     - cd ZEDAT-HPC-LDAP
     - ls -la /usr/share/perl5/Test
     - prove -l t
   tags:
     - perl
```

This test originally failed because a standard Perl library used by the test was not installed on the Gitlab server.  After I installed the missing library, the test still failed and the `ls` in the test displayed the old state of the file system.  Obviously the test had not been re-run and a cached version of the test result was shown.

The problem seems to be that installing the missing library does not change anything within the repository and so Gitlab seems to think that it OK to not re-run the test.  After I modified the test by sticking a `date` in after the `ls` the test passed.

So how can I force a test to be run or, alternatively, how can I disable the caching mechanism?

[Update]

The output from the test is

```
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ date
Fri Nov 22 11:51:33 CET 2019
$ cd ZEDAT-HPC-LDAP
$ ls -la /usr/share/perl5/Test
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Apr 23  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 49 root root 4096 Jun 21 06:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 23  2018 Perl
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Apr 23  2018 Pod
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 7533 Jul  4  2015 Pod.pm
```

whereas logged into the server as user `gitlab-runner` I get

```
gitlab-runner@sc-git:~$ date
Fri Nov 22 12:55:53 CET 2019
gitlab-runner@sc-git:~$ ls -la /usr/share/perl5/Test/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Nov 21 09:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 54 root root  4096 Nov 21 09:53 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 11301 Dec 10  2014 Fatal.pm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov 21 09:53 MockObject
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 23464 Dec  3  2016 MockObject.pm
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 May 31  2018 Net
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Apr 23  2018 Perl
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Apr 23  2018 Pod
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  7533 Jul  4  2015 Pod.pm
```

How can that be?

Answer (score 1):

You can re-run a pipeline using the UI (CI/CD > Pipelines) :

[image]

and choose the branch to run on. Or the using the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#triggering-a-pipeline)

Clearing the cache [manually](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/caching/#clearing-the-cache-manually) is possible clicking the button "Clear Runner caches" next to the "Run Pipeline" :

[image]

Comment: It turns out that the test is being re-run, as show by the output of ```date```, but the output of ```ls``` is incorrect.  I've added the test output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem seems to have been a mismatch between the runner and gitlab itself.  Earlier this week we installed an update of `gitlab-runner` from 12.4.1 to 12.5.0. The package `gitlab-ce` was at 12.4.3.  This afternoon the update for `gitlab-ce` to 12.5.0 arrived, which we duly installed.  Now the weird 'bygone-filesystem' problem has disappeared and I am left with normal, non-timetravelling errors. Hooray!

First Take-away:  Don't install an update just because there's an update.

Second Take-away: Gitlab seems to go in for some extremely bizarre and disturbing caching.

Comment: Turns out the problem still exists even if the versions match.  Another test fails, complaining that a Perl module cannot be found, and the 'ls' within the test shows that it is missing.  However, the same 'ls' run directly in a terminal shows that the module is there 

Comment: The problem is that the test is in fact running on a different host to the one I was expecting.  It seems to be a network issue whereby the IP address for the runner does not always get resolved to the same host.

Comment: It wasn't the network.  The gitlab instance is a virtual machine created by cloning an existing VM.  A runner had already been defined in the original VM, so the clone contained a runner with the same ID.  This is apparently not a good thing.